# C++ Image move on keystoke

Tags: c++, image

I have created a game and gotten help on it from this site before. I have another quick question, Can I move a picture box 5 to the left with the keyboard? With say the arrow keys or any other 2 keys?

I am using Windows Visual Studio 2008 and a Windows Form Application

Comment: What GUI framework are you using -- getting keystrokes is dependent on that.

Comment: I do believe you will need to be a little bit more specific - C++ doesn't know anything about picture boxes or keyboards or arrow keys - your platform and your libs do.

Comment: I am just using a Windows for application from Visual Studio 2008

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Yes you can. That is most certainly possible.

Comment: Any hints on how i could do this?

Comment: What kind of details are you looking for?